# What is the best way to distribute my iOS app to customers?

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program, in-house-distribution, ios-enterprise

I have an iOS app which i want to distribute to my clients. I have almost 30 companies as my clients. Every company has their own webservice from where i get their data. Functionality and graphics will be same for every company. I think i need iOS Developer Enterprise Program to distribute my app to my clients. There are couple of things i am wondering:

1- My clients are companies, not my co-workers. Is there any legal issue if i use iOS Developer Enterprise Program to distribute app to my clients?

2- Do they need to register for any iOS Developer Program to use my app?

3- I went through apple's site and i didn't see any fixed number of devices for iOS Developer Enterprise Program. Is there any?

4- I don't want that any of my client company knows about other so i am not giving them any option to select their webservice when app is installed. It means that i will make seperate binary for every app. Do i need 30 different app ids and provisioning profiles for that or can i use only one? What is the best way to distribute app in this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use the Enterprise program to distribute apps outside of your own company, instead you should look at developing custom b2b apps, these can be distributed through the app store, but aren't visible to normal users.

https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/

Comment: So i have to make 30 copies of the same app with 30 different app ids. And then put them on appstore using VPP. And how will i stop those companies to download other companie's app. I just want to send one app to each company so they can install their specific app on their devices. instead of putting it on appstore. Is there no way to do that?

Comment: If you distribute this way clients will only be able to access the app you have given permissions for, although it goes through the app store it's not actually visible to everyone. You can configure this through iTunes Connect:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/B2B.html